# How to generate Source Insight Call "Cumulative function" Graph

Tags: graph, editor, function-call, call-graph, source-insight

What I mean by cumulative is that the graph should list the functions that call function x and also all the functions called by function x.

Today in the call graph feature of source insight, in a given view you can get either one of those relations in the "Relationship Window".

You can select if you want to do "Function calls" or "Referenced by functions" by selecting the appropriate drop down in the relationship window properties, but is there a way to do both ?  So that I can see the complete tree.

a,b,c == call ==> X == calls ==> d,e,f

(provided my cursor is on function X definition).  Today I can do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

From "Relation Window Options" dialog, choose "Calls and Callers" from "For Functions" drop-down list. I used and it works.